# How can I remove the new do-nothing "settings" control from my Marmalade Android app on HTC One (Credo only?)?

Tags: android, marmalade

I'm working on my first (C++/IwNUI) Marmalade app, which so far works fine, but on Monday one of my devices (an HTC One Android phone, Credo Mobile) had a system update, after which my app, and only my app, now shows what seems to be a "settings" control on top of my app, which can be moved around, but does nothing but clock taps to the app where it is. It's a grey circle with three dots in it, which appears immediately when my app starts to load. Another Android test machine (Samsung Galaxy) does not show this control on my app.

Has anyone else seen this? How might I get it not to appear?

I have asked on the Marmalade forums with no response, and searched here and on the web but I haven't seen any reference to it, so I assume it may be limited to some combination of Marmalade apps, HTC One, and/or Credo Mobile Android phones.

Update: This control appears (on this phone only) on all of the Marmalade example apps I have built too, including IwUI, IwNUI, and plain demos like IwHTTPExample.

Even though this is very specific, I wonder if anyone knows a programmatic way in Marmalade C++ for me to at least get such a settings control to hide or go away?

Comment: As this is likely hardware specific, you might want to make it more obvious that this is the case.

Comment: rad, thanks!  That should help in answering it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to make it go away: "Add android:targetSdkVersion="11" (or higher) to your  element." in the settings file which in my Marmalade project is called AndroidManifest.xml.

It seems like this may be a bug where it thinks there is an "overflow" of a title/menu-bar which isn't even there in these apps. By targeting a later version, it uses a newer "holo" menu, which doesn't do this.

If someone has a better explanation, I'll wait to mark that as the accepted answer.

In case it may help future people confused by all this, here's how I found this. Jared's answer led me to study my Marmalade config files, and the Android developer site where I found [some general somewhat relevant info about what this is](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html), and to search some different terms on the Marmalade forums, which got me to a [relevant question I had missed on the Marmalade community answer pages](https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/10655/android-4-three-dot-options-menu-how-to-disable.html), which led me to [this page which had the suggestion which has the desired effect](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg197061.html).

Comment: I was having the same problem with a phonegap application, and this led me to the right place.. Note: I had to target version 14+ to get rid of it

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you created a new project. Are you seeing this "settings"?

[image]

This is automatically added in every new app. Check your `res` -> `menu` folder. You can remove the "fake" options menu if you like.

Samsung will show this menu if you hit the menu button on the bottom left of the device.

HTC devices will show the options menu in the `ActionBar`/`ToolBar`.

Comment: Mine doesn't look like that - it's just a grey circle with three dots (that are like those three dots) always floating over the UI, moveable, and the phone remembers where it was last dragged, the same no matter which app it is. I will go find the res->menu and see if I can eradicate it there, and report back. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Dronz Let me know! This is an old picture running Android 4.4. You are most likely see 3 dots from AppCompat or a device running Android 5.0+.

Comment: Hmm. I don't see where I actually have a res->menu folder in Marmalade anywhere, though there are some XML settings files. I found several files with project settings in them that I'm poring over looking for something about an options menu.

Comment: Look in your `MainActivity`. You are directly initializing this menu. In a default project, it is usually called `menu.xml`.

Comment: I don't have a menu.xml or a MainActivity. I am guessing you are talking about Android project structure and I think Marmalade's project structure is different, being a cross-platform framework. You have led me down a path that has led to me finding something that works, however. I will post about that in a couple minutes here. This was a great help getting me to find this! Thanks!!

Comment: I was trying to help map from an Android project structure to a Marmalade one. So was this almost the answer you were looking for?

Comment: It was close enough to lead me to find an answer, which I just added.